# global name 's3' not defined using boto?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Boto3 is installed but when I try to use the below function to upload an image to an S3 bucket I get global name 's3' is not defined error.

Is there something I'm missing?

```
import logging
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import os

def upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name=None):

if object_name is None:
    object_name = os.path.basename(file_name)

s3_client = boto3.resource('s3')

try:
    response = s3.client.upload_file(file_name, bucket, 
    object_name)
except ClientError as e:
    logging.error(e)
    return False
return True

upload = upload_file('test1.jpg','mybucket', 'test1.jpg')
```

Comment: You defined `s3_client`. `s3.client` is a `client` property on the value of `s3`, and `s3` is indeed not defined. Closing as typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
response = s3.client.upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name)
```

should be:

```
response = s3_client.upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name)
```